# Prevent account owner from accessing EC2 and Redshift

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

One of our customers wants us to process their data in their own AWS account. They will create an AWS id for us and we will create an environment in their account.

We are concerned that they will have access to our code, intermediate
calculations, database schema etc and our intellectual property (IP) may not be protected.

Our environment consists of a Redshift cluster and EC2 machines running python code. Data is stored in S3.

Are there any steps we can take to prevent the customer from accessing
our environment even when they own the account?

Encryption will not help because the encryption keys are stored in
the account itself, which the account owner can access.
Code obfuscation is another not so good option.

Thanks!

Comment: if you have access to their aws, why does YOUR code have to be in THEIR aws?

Comment: With the EC2 instances at least, you can set up a key only you have access to. But this will not stop them from creating snapshots and attaching then to other instances.

It probably should be the other way around, you create the account, and give them access to what they are allowed access to.

Comment: @MarcB: They do not want their data to be moved out of their environment (raw or processed data).

Comment: @datasage: Yes, creating a snapshot and attaching to their instance is a problem. Also, AWS encryption keys are stored in the same account, owner will be able to access them.

Comment: If the company has legal compliance requirements, I can see why they would not want to allow the data to be moved outside of their control. Assuming you are operating in a jurisdiction with strong IP laws, your contract with them should outline the constraints as to what they can and can't do with your code. If they do misuse the code, then you can sue them for breach of contract.

Comment: @datasage: We are a small startup selling to an overseas customer. We may not be able to detect or enforce breach of contract. But I agree with you, legal contract seems to be best option. I explored technical options but they are either too expensive or too cumbersome to use.